# Deny Update on Columns to ALL Users & Roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, roles

In SQL Server, I have a table where after a row has been inserted, several of the columns never need to be changed (yes it's possible this might change in the future, but unlikely or will be a rare event).  I know that SQL server has column level permissions, and so I wanted to deny updated on these columns for all users, role, current and present.  The T-SQL looks something like this:

```
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.<Table>(<Column1>,<Columns2>,etc) TO ______
```

However it appears that using this command, you have to always specify a user or role at the end.  Is there a way to have it apply to all users current and future?

And yes, I AM WELL AWARE I can use a trigger to throw an error if the columns are changed after an update, or apply the DENY command to all existing users and roles and create a procedure for creating new users and roles that would create the new user/role and automatically apply the update, etc.

Before I consider any of those options, I would see if the DENY Update to all Users option can be done.

Thanks you!

Comment: `CASCADE`? Not quite sure how it works but looks promising

Comment: Looks like that's primarily related to updates and delete on a primary table where other tables have foreign keys linked to the table being modified.

Comment: I meant `DENY CASCADE`, but no I think it doesn't do what you need. Really, this is what roles are for. You assign a user a particular role. If that role does not have write access the the user can't write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enrole all your SQL users in a default role, so that you can do a DENY on that role. For the future one, create a DDL trigger that fire CREATE USER and add it as a member of this role.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best option.  I was hoping there was a way to associate the permission with the table itself, rather than with a role or user.